# Rest Assured Bearer authentication GraphQL

Tags: selenium, graphql, rest-assured, bearer-token

I'm new to learn rest assured and stuck with bearer authentication scenario where i've graphql query and need to pass by generating token first and then pass it through in order to get response result.
I've created following scripts however its generating the token but failed to return the response in second post request as i'm getting   "error": "Bearer token malformed"

```
public class Auth {
    
    @Test
    public void bearerToken() {
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://xyzapi.google.com";
        RequestSpecification request=RestAssured.given();
        JSONObject requestParams = new JSONObject();
        
        requestParams.put("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        requestParams.put("client_id", "fa3f2b6a-3f0b-44b4-a084-ceed3");    
        requestParams.put("client_secret", "WeLzkxgYSrfH3wXTqjuvDoFEN04aV86Osd1UKl9Z52RPh");
        request.header("Content-Type","application/json");
        request.header("Authorization","Basic ZmEzZjJiNmEtM2YwYi00NGI0LWEwODQtY2VlZGVhYjMwNDgzOldlTHpreGdZWODZHUW10QkF5aW43TUNKYnBJY09zZDFVS2w5WjUyUlBo");
        
        request.body(requestParams.toJSONString());
        Response responseFromGeneratedToken  = request.request(Method.POST,"/oauth/token");
        responseFromGeneratedToken.prettyPrint();
        
        
        String jsonString =responseFromGeneratedToken.getBody().asString();
        String tokenGenerated =JsonPath.from(jsonString).get("access_token");
        
        System.out.println("The generated token value is :"+tokenGenerated);
        request.header("Authorization","Bearer "+tokenGenerated);
        request.header("Content-Type","application/json");
        JSONObject requestParams1 = new JSONObject();
        requestParams1.put("query MyQuery","{\r\n"
                + "  Get(EmployeeId: \"\", offset: 0, limit: 2, EmployerId: \"\") {\r\n"
                + "    xyz{\r\n"
                + "      Number\r\n"
                + "      Code\r\n"
                + "      ner\r\n"
                + "      om {\r\n"
                + "       Ratings {\r\n"
                + "          ted\r\n"
                + "          ore\r\n"
                + "        }\r\n"
                + "      }\r\n"
                + "}\r\n"
                + "");
                
    
        request.header("Content-Type","application/json");
        request.body(requestParams1.toJSONString());
        Response Responsefinal=request.request(Method.POST,"/lists/SeniorCitizen/");
        String Responsebody = Responsefinal.getBody().asString();
        System.out.println(Responsebody);
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Did you get access_token at step 1? Did you check the access_token is being sent at step 2? 3. Could you provide the request log? 4. I don't like the idea reusing `RequestSpecification` instance, it's better to use new instance for each request.

Comment: Yes, Token has created in first step , Even tried to print generated token with Bearer keyword first and then tried to pass it using body of payload ( graphQL query ) in post method which is something not working for me , following the console result  
{
    "access_token": "6167b529fac53b0001aec5f484ac36d59f875358",
    "expires_in": 5000,
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
The generated token value is :6167b529fac53b0001aec5f484ac36d59f875358
{
    "error": "Bearer token malformed"
}

Comment: Did you try try this token on Postman to confirm that it's RestAssured' issue, not token?

Comment: Yes ,It working in POSTMAN

Comment: Did you see any issue while passing the GraphQL query, i means the way i've added them as params

Comment: Then compare the request log from Rest-Assured and Postman to find out the difference between these. If you can, pls add both logs to your question.